# Start the count with 1 not 0 and convert to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello everyone how can i start the count with 1 not 0 and convert it into ajax

```
$sqlb = "SELECT count(item_id) AS cart_counter 
         FROM temp_cart 
         WHERE temp_id='".$_SESSION['temp_id']."'";
$resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cart_counter=$rowb['cart_counter'];
    echo "$cart_counter";
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.rotate').click(function(){
            var rotate = $(this).index()+1;
            $("#cart_counter").load("cart_counter.php");
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You mean this does egal to 1 even the count() of your Query was 0 ?

Comment: Start by telling us WHAT is not working

Comment: its working but the count start from zero not one. so i want to change it into one

Comment: which count you refer to?

Comment: the counting of numbers it always start from 0 when i click the the button